# mongo single replicate which was converted using Ops Manager automation need oplog?

Tags: mongodb

I have converted standalone to single replica set using Ops Manager Automation and activated backup so its working fine. when I see .conf file I do not OplogsizeMB parameter, so my question is do we need add oplogsizemb parameter to have continuos oplog slice backups of mongodb to Ops Manager or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to add it - it's an [optional parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#replication.oplogSizeMB).

If you don't set it, then the mongod process will automatically allocate a fixed amount of space for the oplog: typically 5% of available disk space.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
The reason I thought of adding oplog is, because ops manager backup oplog is falling behind and I had to resync. So I was thinking to create oplog with large size so that it won`t fall behind. Let me know if this thing works.

Comment: Ah, your secondary node is lagging? You should have mentioned that in your question!
Increasing the oplog size _might_ help, if there are times with fewer writes , allowing your secondary to catch up. But if your writes are coming in fast _all the time_, and your secondary can't keep up, then a larger oplog will only delay the inevitable. You need to make your secondary able to keep up, perhaps with faster disk i/o.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I thought of adding oplog is, because ops manager backup oplog is falling behind and I had to resync. So I was thinking to create oplog with large size so that it won`t fall behind. Let me know if this thing works.

Comment: Hi Rocky; the extra information is useful, but you shouldn't post it as an answer here. It really belongs in your question, so you should _edit_ your question to include the clarification.